# How to filter by a specific value from XML via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am inputing some XML data and using XPath to pull relevant information out. The XML is limited and not much information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RepeaterData><Version />
<items>
    <item>Booked</item>
    <item>Booked</item>
    <item>Collected</item>
    <item>Collected</item>
</items>
</RepeaterData>
```

The below syntax shows all entries:

```
//items/*
```

Question is: 
how do I make the XPath to pull information for [Collected] only.

Comment: why would somebody vote this topic down?? how SAD must you be!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```
//items/*[text()='Collected']
```

And here's a link of other useful xpath functions https://way2tutorial.com/xml/xpath_functions_with_examples.php

Comment: does this also work if you want to add more //items like //ItemDescription //ItemDate and then finally filter all to say //ItemStatus[text()='Collected'] ??

Comment: Do you mean if you add other tags inside the `<items>` tag, like `<itemdescription>` or `<itemdate>`? Either way you can just use this `//*[starts-with(name(), 'item')]//*[text()='Collected']`. This will capture every tag that starts with `item` and text of 'Collected'.

Comment: yes that is what I mean. Imagine there are 10 items of which 5 of them are collected. The aim is to show all the information (ItemDescription, ItemNr, ItemDate etc etc.) but only where ItemStatus is 'Collected' . I tried the code you suggested but does not show all data....